# javascript: how to execute a function stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, parameters

I need to store a function alongside with its parameters on an object, that is to say something like this:

```
function myFunction(params) {
   console.log('Params',params);
}

const obj = {method: myFunction, params: [params]};
```

how can I construct this function and its parameters again in order to execute it from what I have in `obj`?

Comment: Note that the `)` (closing parenthesis) just before the `;` at the end of `const obj = {method: myFunction, params: [params]);` should be a `}` (closing curly brace).

Comment: What do you mean by "construct"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "construct," but you can call it like this:

```
obj.method(obj.params);
```

Live Example:

```js
function myFunction(params) {
   console.log('Params',params);
}

const obj = {method: myFunction, params: ["example"]};
// Note: Fixed typo −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^

obj.method(obj.params); // Shows: Params example
```

Comment: Oh, that was quick answer... I had something like this, but it was failing... thank you, this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

more beautiful but requires ES6

```
const  myFunction = (params)  => {
   console.log('Params',params);
}
```

Now you can put it in your object how you did.
you can execute it by using

`obj.method(obj.params)`

Answer (score 1):

How about using a closure to store the params and then returning another function? Then you wouold not have to store them within an object, like so:

```js
function createClosure(params) {
  return function {
    console.log(`Params: ${params}`);
  }
}
```

or in ES6 Syntax:

```js
const createClosure = (params) => () => {
  console.log(`Params: ${params}`);
};
```

In both cases, you could store and call the function like this:

```js
const myClosure = createClosure(params);

// then somewhere else
myClosure(); // prints params
```